# Library to read a MySQL dump?

Tags: python, api, mysql

I am looking for a library that will allow me to read a mysql dump.

I don't want to have to create a MySQL database and import the library and use the MySQL API. I would prefer simply a library that can parse the mysql dump format.

I prefer a python library, but other scripting languages are okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import into MySQL and dump using --xml seems to be the best option.

I wrote up the reasoning in this blog post: [Use flag –xml when you run mysqldump](http://blog.metaoptimize.com/2009/10/14/use-flag-xml-when-you-run-mysqldump/)

Comment: A useful write-up (BTW you're right - I was in fact looking for MediaWiki imports when I stumbled on the above).

Answer (score 1):

I came across [sqldump.py](http://gnosis.cx/download/pywikipedia/sqldump.py) while looking for something similar - might be of use...

Comment: True, but this is only for wikipedia SQL dumps. A useful script for another task.